# cannot identify string encoding

Tags: c#, encoding

What encoding do I need to use to encode the string `document.write('website%40site.com');` so that it will look like the string below?

> %64%6f%63%75%6d%65%6e%74%2e%77%72%69%74%65%28%27%3c%61%20%68%72%65%66%3d%5c%22%6d%61%69%6c%74%6f%3a%63%68%75%6d%61%6b%73%68%6c%69%61%68%40%6d%61%69%6c%2e%72%75%5c%22%3e%63%68%75%6d%61%6b%73%68%6c%69%61%68%40%6d%61%69%6c%2e%72%75%3c%5c%2f%61%3e%27%29%3b

Comment: your string decodes to `document.write('<a href=\"mailto:chumakshliah@mail.ru\">chumakshliah@mail.ru<\/a>');` see http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: except, now you just now how the bytes are encoded - is this ascii? or some other encoding? it is hard to tell. in fact, only heuristics are really possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the same type of encoding as URL encoding, except that all characters are encoded instead of only the ones that actually need encoding. Each byte is converted into a two digit hexadecimal number, prefixed with `%`.

You can encode the string using UTF-8, then convert each byte to a hex code:

```
string encoded = String.Concat(
  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("document.write('website%40site.com');")
  .Select(b => "%" + b.ToString("x2"))
  .ToArray()
);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that's what I needed! string xxx = string.Empty;
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("document.write('" + Page.Company.EMail + "');").Select(b => "%" + b.ToString("x2")).ToList().ForEach(d =>
        {
            xxx += d;
        });

Comment: How can you tell it is UTF8 rather than ASCII or one of the ISO 8859 encodings?  I can't discern that.

Comment: @throbbing salami: Don't use `+=` to concatenate strings in a loop, I corrected my example to use `String.Concat`.

Comment: David Heffeman: The string doesn't contain any characters where the encoding differs, so it doesn't matter which encoding is used.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal encoded ASCII:

```
%3c%5c%2f%61%3e = <\/a>
```

and it is rare to see ASCII encoded like this, Unicode on the other hand is not.

Answer (score 1):

That's either ASCII or UTF-8 or one of the 8 bit supersets of ASCII.  Impossible to say for sure.

Your best bet is to read the documentation of whatever function or program you are trying to pass it to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [online encoder/decoder](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/encode-decode.html) which does what you want.